# elFinder limit folder size

Tags: php, elfinder

I'm using [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) and I would know if it's possible to limit the users folder size to 200Mo?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score -2):

If you talk about limit the size of uploaded folder then it is possible by using uploadMaxSize in connector.php.

```
$opts = array(
'roots'  => array(
    array(
        'driver'     => 'LocalFileSystem',
        'path'       => '/path/to/files/',
        'uploadMaxSize' => '500k' //here which you want to give
);
```

see this : https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#uploadMaxSize

Comment: uploadMaxSize will only prevent the upload of files larger than 500k. That wouldnt prevent someone uploading 1000000 files of 499k.